# PHP - Getting an "[filename] is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous" alert on an ics file in Google Chrome

Tags: php, wordpress, google-chrome, icalendar

I've built a plugin in WordPress that allows the creation of autogenerated .ics files. The header are these two lines:-

```
header('Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename=' . get_the_title() . '.ics');
```

I've uploaded it to a new site, and whenever I download the .ical file I get an error saying "[filename] is not commonly downloaded and may be dangerous" within Google Chrome and to download the file I need to select "Keep". This only occurs in Google Chrome (Safari / Firefox download the file as intended).

The domain is registered approximately at the time of writing 24 hours old. Here is what I've done so far.

- Installed a different plugin on the same domain, same server that does .ical file export (The Events Calendar), test created an event with ical export. Done the export unsuccessfully (I still get the error).
- Installed both The Events Calendar & my plugin on a different domain, different sever. Test created an event in both The Events Calendar & my plugin. Done an export in both plugins successfully (I get no errors).
- Installed both The Events Calendar & my plugin on a different domain, same server. Test created an event in both The Events Calendar & my plugin. Done an export in both plugins successfully (I get no errors).

This leads me to believe that the domain is possibly an issue. It is brand new and may need whitelisting(?) in Chrome. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: are you running your site in https?

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes, all sites mentioned above are HTTPS using LetsEncrypt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. If anybody else gets this issue, it's because it's a brand new site. After a while (about a week for me), it corrected itself.

Gabor's answer below is half way there, if you sign up to Google Search Console and go to Security & Manual Actions > Security, you will see if your site has any security issues.

If you don't, then *eventually* the warning will disappear. Again, it was about a week, but you may be different.

I guess possible advice is to register a domain before needing it.

Answer (score 0):

Possible Chrome solution below the Firefox one:

In Firefox there's a setting to disable it for warning you against it here:

> Firefox > Options > Privacy & Security > Security > Warn you about unwanted and uncommon software

That's not great because it only solves it on your computer.

Firefox seems to compare that link / domain to a list they have and then make a decision. For Chrome a more permanent solution would be to add the link / domain in webmaster tools to a list of allowed links, per https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/12956242?hl=en, referencing https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/3258249.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be related to the Content-Disposition: inline?

What happens if you change that to Content-Disposition: attachment, and thus force a download?

Comment: No joy unfortunately. That was something else I tested (sorry forgot to mention that!)